# Дополнение словаря двумя переменными

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне необходимо дополнять словарь переменной содержащей *ключ* и переменной содержащей *значение*. Однако добавить получается только значение, потому что "update" не воспринимает name, как переменную. Прикладываю пример ввода и вывода. Если мой способ добавления данных в словарь в корне неверный, то подскажите, пожалуйста, другой вариант.

[image: Пример входных данных]

[image: Пример выходных данных]

```
all_members = {}
name = input('Имя: ')
comment = input('Комментарий: ')
all_members.update(name=comment)
f = open('list.bin', 'wb')
try:
    pickle.dump(all_members, f)
finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: Мне кажется, вам не помешает заглянуть в справку по update

Comment: `all_members.update({name: comment})`, и кстати вместо `pickle` для словаря и списка словарей гораздо удобней использовать `json.dump()`, что позволяет ознакомиться с содержимым дампа. Там есть некоторые нюансы сериализации, но судя по коду Вам столкновение с ними пока не грозит.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вышло так, как я и хотел.

Comment: @Doshi Но использование update здесь лишнее. Добавление пары в словарь - базовая операция, а создание нового словаря и слияние словарей -  просто ни к чему.

Comment: По задаче мне необходимо было сделать так, чтобы можно было создавать новые карточки, просматривать их, удалять их и редактировать. В конце всё это должно сохраняться в отдельный файл, для дальнейшего использования. Как вы считаете, что нужно сделать, чтобы было правильнее?

Comment: Как создавать - я ответил. Как удалять - [посмотрите справку](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict), есть метод `del`

Answer (score 3):

Задание элемента словаря:

```
allmembers[name]=comment
```

Answer (score 1):

Вроде так

`all_members[name] = comment`